# Why python not show in path icon?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qicon

I wrote below code

```
import sys,time
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
sys.path.append(r"C:\Users\hpaalm\Desktop")
a=QPushButton()
a.setIcon(QIcon('1.png'))
a.show()
app.exec_()
```

when i run it in IDE, it show my icon, but when run it in CMD it not show icon. what is problem?

```
python C:\Users\hpaalm\Desktop\a.py
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sys.path` contains a list of paths where python imports the modules, this does not serve to import files, icons or similar resources. Instead it is best to create a function that binds the directory path with the filename and return the full path of the icon:

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidgets

ICON_DIR = r"C:\Users\hpaalm\Desktop"

def get_path_icon(filename):
    return os.path.join(ICON_DIR, filename)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    a = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
    a.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(get_path_icon('1.png')))
    a.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```